# How to find available free pages in system(linux machine)?

Tags: linux, command-line, memory

I want to find how much pages are free in system from shell(command line). I have Embedded Linux with 1GB RAM with TI processor.

How to find total, used and free pages information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `free` command shows memory statistics including free pages.

You can use other tools, like `top` or even graphical front-ends, which will report the same information - it all comes from the same place.